# Kafka Invalid Topic Exception for Every topic! why?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I installed latest confluent platform Kafka on Ubuntu server.  Now when I try to get consume from topic I get an error for all the topics that were working last friday and any new ones I create.

```
kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic distance2
```

topic created distance2

```
   kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic  distance2  --from-beginning
```

[2020-06-01 08:00:27,746] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-56224-1, groupId=console-consumer-56224] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {distance2 =INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2020-06-01 08:00:27,747] ERROR [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-56224-1, groupId=console-consumer-56224] Metadata response reported invalid topics [distance2 ] (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2020-06-01 08:00:27,748] ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)

```
  org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: Invalid topics: [distance2 ]
Processed a total of 0 messages
```

As a matter of principal it seems that the reason why something is invalid should be available. How do i find the reason?

Comment: There seems to be a whitespace at the end of the topic name in the Exception?

Comment: Ok, thats an interesting observation let me see ..

Comment: Yeah that seems to be it.

Comment: Yep thats it. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I have reached my question limit. I have installed Kafka on Ubuntu and start with systemctl.  Right now I cannot get logs for connectors except by tail syslog at /var/log and I dont see the log for connectors anywhere. I did find the log4j and it seems to be configured to me to write to file but cannot see that it wrote to a file anywhere.  Nor how I would listen to it in standard out. Only tail of whole syslog seems to work but its not that good for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error

```
[WARN ] 2021-01-13 19:24:44.516 [tx.id=] [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] NetworkClient - 
[Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 574 : {publish.data.dev =INVALID_TOPIC_EXCEPTION}
```

The error occurred due to space after the topic name in the property file i.e "publish.data.dev "
Fixed after removing the space

Answer (score 3):

To provide additional information besides that in the comment section (from documentation):

> The client has attempted to perform an operation on an invalid topic.
> For example the topic name is too long, contains invalid characters
> etc. This exception is not retriable because the operation won't
> suddenly become valid.

Valid characters are '-', '.', '_'.